# NodeJS - Nested Promise inside a for loop

Tags: node.js, api, express, server, promise

I am trying to do a call which retrieves a list of categories. Inside this call I want to loop through the categories and retrieve the items for each category and return them all together. My call retrieves the categories perfectly before I added the loop to retrieve the items.

To double check my call to another controller works, I added a proof of concept block of code which you can see below is commented out. So I know it isn't the call to an external class.

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
MenuCategory = mongoose.model('MenuCategory');

module.exports = function(menuItemController) {
  var mod = {
    listEntireMenu(req, res) {

      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var entireMenu = [];

        MenuCategory.find({}, function(err, menuCategories) {
           if (err) {
             return reject(err)
           } else {

             //---------------------------
             // PROOF OF CONCEPT THAT CALL TO OTHER CONTROLLER WORKS
             //---------------------------
             //
             // var categoryWithItems = menuCategories[0].toObject();
             // req.body.menuCategoryID = categoryWithItems._id;
             // menuItemController.listAllMenuItemsByCategory(req, res).then((menuItems) => {
             //   if(menuItems)
             //   {
             //     return resolve(menuItems);
             //   }
             //   else
             //   {
             //     return { success: false }
             //   }
             // });
             //-----------------------------

            for (var i = 0; i < menuCategories.length; i++) {
                  var categoryWithItems = menuCategories[i].toObject();
                  var subItems = [];

                  req.body.menuCategoryID = categoryWithItems._id;
                  menuItemController.listAllMenuItemsByCategory(req, res).then((menuItems) => {
                  if(menuItems)
                  {
                    subItems = menuItems;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    return { success: false }
                  }
                });

                categoryWithItems.tester = { "itemsList" : subItems };
                entireMenu.push(categoryWithItems);

             }
             return resolve(entireMenu)
           }
         });
       }).then((menuCategories) => {

         if(menuCategories)
         {
           return menuCategories
         }
         else
         {
           return { success: false }
         }
       });
    },
   }
   return mod;
};
```

What I actually get returned is this :

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ed16fxxxxxxxx95676e37",
        "locationID": "5ed16xxxxxxxx7295676e36",
        "menuCategoryName": "Category One",
        "Created_date": "2020-05-29T20:26:34.991Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "tester": {
            "itemsList": []
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ed170xxxxxx95676e38",
        "locationID": "5ed16xxxxxxxx7295676e36",
        "menuCategoryName": "Category Two",
        "Created_date": "2020-05-29T20:26:48.799Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "tester": {
            "itemsList": []
        }
    }
]
```

Here is the call from the route.js :

```
app.get('/api/listEntireMenu', (req, res) => {
    menuCategoryController.listEntireMenu(req, res).then(menuCategories => res.json(menuCategories));
})
```

It never writes the subItems into the object. Is this an async issue or something else? I am not sure how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i believe the reason the result of your call to resolve is being returned before the requests are able to complete...for this you need to wait until all the promises or requests have finished properly and returned.

There are two ways you can do this: you could either run them one by one and wait for each one to finish first or run them all concurrently until all of them are done.

Ofcourse the fastest way to do it would be to run them all concurrently so lets go for that way:

so to start, let us not use the for loop and instead remap the iterable array menuCategories to promises of the request, we will use your proof of concept code to make the array of promises

```
//...
Promise.all(
  menuCategories.map((category) => {
    let category_with_items = category.toObject();

    req.body.menuCategoryID = category_with_items._id;

    // here we need to return this since its the promise we are remapping to
    return menuItemController.listAllMenuItemsByCategory(req, res)
      .then((menuitems) => {
         if(menuItems) {
           return menuitems;
         }

         throw 'No menu items found'
      });
  });
)
// each promise will return menuitems so we have to wait for all the promises to complete
// then with the results of each promise we push the items into the entire menu
.then((itemslist) => {
  itemslist.forEach((items) => entireMenu.push(items));

  return entireMenu;
})
// lastly we need to handle any errors from the promises
.catch((error) => { success: false });
//...
```

So now we have...

```
listEntireMenu(req, res) {
  return MenuCategory.find({}, function(err, menuCategories) {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    } else {
      entireMenu = [];

      return /* the promise all call from above will go right here */;
    }
}
```

I hope it works out, thanks...

Comment: I haven't managed to get this working. I think it is because my route is expecting a resolve to return the data. I use resolves throughout but can't seem to make it work with the Promise.all you uggested.